# Stylize map with google map api2 for Android

Tags: android, google-maps

Is there a way to **stylize map** with google map api2 for **android**? All I need is to make background gray and roads white and turn off some markers like bus stops.

I know it is posible with google javaScript maps api v3. It works like this:

```
   var pinkParksStyles = [
{
 featureType: "all",
 stylers: [
  { saturation: -80 }
 ]
},
{
 featureType: "poi.park",
 stylers: [
  { hue: "#ff0023" },
  { saturation: 40 }
 ]
}
];

map.setOptions({styles: pinkParksStyles});
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling#styling_the_default_map

But I can not find something like this for android.

Comment: As of September 2016 the map styling is now available for Android and iOS. You can find more details in: https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.es/2016/09/custom-map-styling-with-google-maps.html

Answer (score 1):

Styled maps are not currently supported for the Google Maps Android API

Comment: Please update answer: now styled maps are supported for the Google Maps Android API.