# Desaturating Google Maps in a native Android App (API V2)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2

The Google Maps API V3 allows for advanced map styling options such as desaturation etc.
However, this API is only for use in webview. Coding a native Android Maps app, one has to use the Google Maps API V2 for Android, which does not allow for these advanced styling options.

Is there a way/workaround for applying advanced styles to a native Android Maps app, specifically desaturating a map?

THX

Comment: I don't think that is possible as of 3.1.36 and can only suggest posting a feature request on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype=Android2).

Comment: You can consider using phonegap to build an android app that uses Google Maps API V3 instead of the native api if it suits your purpose

Comment: Thanks, guys! @tony, does phonegap allow me to build wrappers that I can run inside of a native app? The app still has to be a native one, not a wrapper.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stylize map with google map api2 for Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722418/stylize-map-with-google-map-api2-for-android)