# Google Maps Android API - Styled Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-android-api-1

From what I have read so far, it seems that there is no way to style Google Maps via the [Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/?hl=en).

Has anyone seen differently or know a way to style Google Maps on Android (change feature colors, etc.)?

From what I have seen, the only alternative to a full map library for Android (or iOS) is [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/), but their Android library is still under heavy development.

Comment: As of this writing, this is not possible as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/lite) . You should instead consider using Google Maps Javascript API if in case you really needed a styled maps.

Comment: I had overlooked that bottom box explicitly stating that, thanks.

Comment: Finally this feature is available for Android and iOS. You can refer to the following post for more details: https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.es/2016/09/custom-map-styling-with-google-maps.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stylize map with google map api2 for Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722418/stylize-map-with-google-map-api2-for-android)

Answer (score 1):

Google introduced Cloud-based Map Styling (however it is in Beta now). Using this feature, it is possible to set up a Map Id and a Map Style in Google Cloud Platform and to use it in the Android App (the only thing you need to do in the app is to specify the Map Id).

Here are the details:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/cloud-based-map-styling

PS Here is the description of the 'old' option where you need to create a special json file and use it in the Android app to get a styled map:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/styling

Answer (score 0):

We can create styled maps as follows in android:

StyledMapDemoActivity.java

```
public class StyledMapDemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private GoogleMap mMap = null;

private static final String TAG = StyledMapDemoActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String SELECTED_STYLE = "selected_style";
// Stores the ID of the currently selected style, so that we can re-apply it when
// the activity restores state, for example when the device changes orientation.
private int mSelectedStyleId = R.string.style_label_default;

// These are simply the string resource IDs for each of the style names. We use them
// as identifiers when choosing which style to apply.
private int mStyleIds[] = {
        R.string.style_label_retro,
        R.string.style_label_night,
        R.string.style_label_grayscale,
        R.string.style_label_no_pois_no_transit,
        R.string.style_label_default,
};

private static final LatLng SYDNEY = new LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2093);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mSelectedStyleId = savedInstanceState.getInt(SELECTED_STYLE);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.styled_map_demo);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
            (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // Store the selected map style, so we can assign it when the activity resumes.
    outState.putInt(SELECTED_STYLE, mSelectedStyleId);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    mMap = map;
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(SYDNEY, 14));
    setSelectedStyle();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.styled_map, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_style_choose) {
        showStylesDialog();
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Shows a dialog listing the styles to choose from, and applies the selected
 * style when chosen.
 */
private void showStylesDialog() {
    // mStyleIds stores each style's resource ID, and we extract the names here, rather
    // than using an XML array resource which AlertDialog.Builder.setItems() can also
    // accept. We do this since using an array resource would mean we would not have
    // constant values we can switch/case on, when choosing which style to apply.
    List<String> styleNames = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int style : mStyleIds) {
        styleNames.add(getString(style));
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.style_choose));
    builder.setItems(styleNames.toArray(new CharSequence[styleNames.size()]),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    mSelectedStyleId = mStyleIds[which];
                    String msg = getString(R.string.style_set_to, getString(mSelectedStyleId));
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d(TAG, msg);
                    setSelectedStyle();
                }
            });
    builder.show();
}

/**
 * Creates a {@link MapStyleOptions} object via loadRawResourceStyle() (or via the
 * constructor with a JSON String), then sets it on the {@link GoogleMap} instance,
 * via the setMapStyle() method.
 */
private void setSelectedStyle() {
    MapStyleOptions style;
    switch (mSelectedStyleId) {
        case R.string.style_label_retro:
            // Sets the retro style via raw resource JSON.
            style = MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.mapstyle_retro);
            break;
        case R.string.style_label_night:
            // Sets the night style via raw resource JSON.
            style = MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.mapstyle_night);
            break;
        case R.string.style_label_grayscale:
            // Sets the grayscale style via raw resource JSON.
            style = MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.mapstyle_grayscale);
            break;
        case R.string.style_label_no_pois_no_transit:
            // Sets the no POIs or transit style via JSON string.
            style = new MapStyleOptions("[" +
                    "  {" +
                    "    \"featureType\":\"poi.business\"," +
                    "    \"elementType\":\"all\"," +
                    "    \"stylers\":[" +
                    "      {" +
                    "        \"visibility\":\"off\"" +
                    "      }" +
                    "    ]" +
                    "  }," +
                    "  {" +
                    "    \"featureType\":\"transit\"," +
                    "    \"elementType\":\"all\"," +
                    "    \"stylers\":[" +
                    "      {" +
                    "        \"visibility\":\"off\"" +
                    "      }" +
                    "    ]" +
                    "  }" +
                    "]");
            break;
        case R.string.style_label_default:
            // Removes previously set style, by setting it to null.
            style = null;
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
    mMap.setMapStyle(style);
}
```

}

StyledMapDemoActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```